# httpclient.execute() hangs when server is deployed to GAE

Tags: android, google-app-engine, servlets, httpclient, socket-timeout-exception

I have a problem calling a servlet from my Android app when the server is deployed to App Engine. 
The call works fine with the local server but when I deploy it, the call just hangs or throws a SocketTimeoutException if I set a timeout for the httpclient.
At the moment my servlet does nothing (so there is no way it could be taking too much time to do its work).

The code I'm using

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL+"/fileupload");
InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(stream, 1000);
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    // file uploaded successfully!
                        Log.e("ok","resp "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                    } else {
                        Log.e("runtime exp","couldn't handle req"+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                        throw new RuntimeException("server couldn't handle request");
                    }
```

What I want to know is what could possibly make this code run fine on localhost but not when the server is deployed to App Engine. 
Any input is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the appengine logs to see if the request even reaches the server , and if so what sort of error do you get ?

Comment: I have checked, and the request never reaches the server. However, if i type the servlet URL in the browser, the request is ok and the servlet is started.

Comment: That would suggest the problem is in your Android app.

Comment: I think so too but this exact code works in localhost. So maybe there's something more I need to do to get it to work when the server is deployed but I really don't know what.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. All the post requests with params hang after the user receives a session cookie from the server. The request doesnt even get made to the server. Did you figure out what was wrong?

Comment: Sorry to say I never figured it out